# Gathering statistics on a resourcePool

Tags: anylogic

I want to get some statistics on some of the resources I have in AnyLogic. For instance, I have a forklift agent and a resourcePool of forklift and I want to get the hourly utilization and the total distance traveled by all forklifts in the pool. I know I can click on the resourcePool icon and see the utilization, but I want to get that with the traveled distance updated and saved every hour. 
Sorry I'm new to this and took me few months of learning to get my model straight

Thank you

Comment: Hi, far too many questions muddled into one. Please split them into separate issues and follow this guide to clarify each one: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello Genjamin. Sorry about that and I just limited the question to the resource utilization and distance

Answer (score 0):

First, you must create an agent type for your resources. With that in place, you can record anything anytime using datasets or default AnyLogic logging capability.

See some example models using resource pools with custom agent types such as "Lead acid battery production" and many more.

PS: Recording distance travelled is done automatically if you apply default logging but it is a bit more involved if you want to do it manually.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have created an agent for the forklifts and then added a resource pool for them. When I drag a dataset to the agent and try to look for distance function in the "Vertical axis value" textbox I get functions such as getDistance which used to calculate the distance between two points. When I search for utilization in that textbox I get nothing in return. Is there a reference of the list of functions that can be used to fill the dataset?

Comment: You can fill a dataset with anything you like. You will need to code this yourself though, if you do not want to use the default AnyLogic agent logging (which includes total distance travelled). Tracking exact distance can be tricky for free-movers so I suggest you check default logging first

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry for bugging you, but the reason I;m asking because the professional version my school has is a bit old- 7.1.2 and I'm also personally have the learning version 8.5.2. So in the new version, I can just check the log box under the database editor and I'm ready to go, while I can't find the log in the old version. There is no database editor and even the help of that version has no content on logs. By any chance, do you know if there is a logging option in 7.2 or not?

Comment: There is not in AL7, no. No logging and no database. AL8 models are also not compatible with AL7 (but the other way is possible)